# How can I use Translation with Transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, translation

I Download a translation dataset for ENg Span  language and tried to practice for purpose learning this is my first time,can anyone help to implement the requirement for practice below to give more understanding
http://www.manythings.org/anki/
Note: I am trying to use Spanish-English, which was tested.
Define the load_data() function to return input and target sentences

```
def load_data(path: pathlib.Path) -> Tuple[List[str], List[str]]:
    ########## Implement your solution BELOW #############


    ############# Implement your solution ABOVE ###########
    return target, input
```

Proivde the filename (fname) to the get_file to download the text file.

Use the load_data function to load the target and input sentences from the downloaded file.

```
############# Implement your solution BELOW ############  

############ Implement your solution ABOVE ##############

text_file = keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=file_name,
    origin="http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/spa-eng.zip",
    extract=True)

############ Implement your solution BELOW ##############

############# Implement your solution ABOVE ############
```

Run this cell to see some examples.

```
for _ in range(5):
    index = random.choice(range(len(target)))
    print(f'#{index}\nENG: {target[index]}\nESP: {input[index]}')
```

Define the make_train_validation_test_sets function.
Make target-input pairs.
Split them into the usual 3 sets: train-validation-test in e.g. 70%, 15%, 15% ratio respectively.
Don't forget to shuffle them before splitting!

```
def make_train_validation_test_sets(target: List[str], input: List[str]) -> Tuple[List[Tuple[str,str]],List[Tuple[str,str]],List[Tuple[str,str]],List[Tuple[str,str]]]:
    ######## Implement your solution BELOW ##########

    ########### Implement your solution ABOVE ############
    return all_pairs, train_pairs, val_pairs, test_pairs

all_pairs, train_pairs, val_pairs, test_pairs = make_train_validation_test_sets(target, input)

print(f"{len(all_pairs)} total pairs")
print(f"{len(train_pairs)} training pairs")
print(f"{len(val_pairs)} validation pairs")
print(f"{len(test_pairs)} test pairs")
```

To handle the non-English text, define a custum_standardization function which will process the foreign input.
Use the tf_text and tf.strings modules to:
Normalize the data in an NFKD utf8 form
Convert to lower case.
Replace puctuation and special characters. (Hint:Use regex.)
Add a '[start]' and '[end]' word to the two ends of the sentence.

### The tensorflow_text package contains a unicode normalize operation

```
def custom_standardization(text: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    ########## Implement your solution BELOW ###########

    ########## Implement your solution ABOVE ###########
    return text

example_text: str
######### Implement your solution BELOW ##########

######### Implement your solution ABOVE  ##########
example = tf.constant(example_text)
print(example.numpy().decode())
print(custom_standardization(example).numpy().decode())
```

Define two TextVectorization instances, one for English and one for the other language.
Use the pre-defined parameters.
Make sure to use the custom_standardization on the instance corresponding the foreign language.
Use 'int' as output_mode
Use the adapt method of the TextVectorization to "fit" them to the corresponding training data.

```
vocab_size = 15000
sequence_length = 20
######### Implement your solution BELOW ###########

########## Implement your solution ABOVE ##########

print(f'english vocabulary: {eng_vectorization.get_vocabulary()[:10]}')
print(f'foreign vocabulary: {spa_vectorization.get_vocabulary()[:10]}')
```

To process the inputs properly the dataset needs to be formatted.

The transformer receives two inputs:

The first 0..N tokens of the source sequence -> the input of the encoder

The first 0..N-1 tokens of the target sequence -> the input of the decoder

Has onelabel sequence (the target sequence):

The last 1..N tokens of the target sequence

def format_dataset(eng:str, spa:str):
eng_vec: tf.Tensor = eng_vectorization(eng)
spa_vec: tf.Tensor = spa_vectorization(spa)

```
  ####### Implement your solution BELOW #######

    ######## Implement your solution ABOVE #######
    return ({"encoder_inputs": encoder_inputs, "decoder_inputs": decoder_inputs,}, target)


# This cell prepares the Datasets by using the format_dataset function.
BUFFER_SIZE = 2048
BATCH_SIZE = 16
def make_dataset(pairs: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    eng_texts, spa_texts = zip(*pairs)
    eng_texts = list(eng_texts)
    spa_texts = list(spa_texts)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((eng_texts, spa_texts))
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.map(format_dataset) # Here is the formatting
    
    return dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).prefetch(BATCH_SIZE).cache()
train_ds = make_dataset(train_pairs)
val_ds = make_dataset(val_pairs)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking you to fill the gaps one after each other